# Properties of $\sum\limits_{n\ge2}\frac{n(n-1)x^n}{n!}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, exponential-function

This is from an MCQ Contest.

> for all integer $n$ greater than or equal to $2$
>   Let $$\forall n\geq 2\qquad u_n=\dfrac{n(n-1)x^n}{n!}, \qquad  x\in \mathbb{R}$$
>
> 1. for all  $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, the series with general term $u_n$ is convergent and has the sum $x^{2}e^{x}$
> 2. the series with general term $u_n$ is convergent if and only if  $|x|<1$
> 3. the series with general term $u_n$ is convergent if and only if  si $|x|>1$
> 4. for all  $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^{*}$, the series with general term $u_n$ is convergent if and only if $|x|=1$

My thoughts

1. True

it's true that $u_n$ convergent since the ratio test gives us :
$$|\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}|=\dfrac{|x|}{n+1}\to 0  < 1$$ then the series converges absolutely beside its sum 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n-2)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+2}}{n!}=x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} $$

- Since $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\  \sum u_{n}$ is convergent
  so implies that 2 3 and 4 are False  because it convergent for all  $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
- Is my proof correct

Comment: To compute the $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n-2)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+2}}{n!}=x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: The sum over$u_k$ kdoes converge to $x^2 e^x$ for all real x